# ecmascript/javascript to check current status of timer job

Tags: javascript, client-object-model, timer-jobs

I want to show sharepoint notification when user opens a list form using oob. I am basically doing some sync with external list and sharepoint using timer job.

For this i want to check if a specific timer job is currently running or check the status a timer job and accordingly notify user the status. The information should contain last successful run and the next scheduled time. Also if the job is currently running than notify user.

Is this possible? Can anyone give me a tutorial or guidance link to check timer job status and to manipulate on timer classes? Basically i want to display notification as shown in [this link](https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/devwiki/articles/pages/sharepoint-showing-notification-and-status-message-using-sp-js.aspx) .

Answer (score 0):

I do not think it is possible to directly work with Timer Jobs through the client object.

All the options I can come up with requires some Server Object Model code, like:

- Do a webpart / user control that checks the Timer Job status from code behind and pushes out a javascript that shows the status message.
- Creating a webservice that is called by javascript, and in turn checks the Timer Job status. The javascript can then show the status messiage